# Is there a way to get device type

Tags: appium

Application UI is different on phone and tablet. In order to create kind of a page factory I need to know which device tests are running on.
So, is it possible to verify whether test is running on phone or tablet? 
In other words I wonder if it's possible to somehow get device type.

Comment: I am not follow you, When you insert the desired capabilities you have to set the device name, Means you know the device where you want to run the tests. Please explain where I am wrong.

Comment: @Eugene, desired capabilities are strings. So, anything could be written there or not written at all. The question is whether appium itself knows where tests are running and if so, whether it's possible to get such info. Thanks.